# Adding (Mean +/- 2 Sigma) lines in box plot

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data set on which I would like to make a boxplot in R. I was able to do it simply (here I used just some sample data) by the following commands in R console:

```
x <- rnorm(100);

y <- rnorm(100);

boxplot(x, y, col=rainbow(2))
```

[image]

Now what I really want is to show the (mean +/- (2 or 3)*sigma) marks for my data set on top of the above boxplot. I do know standard deviation and mean is not robust statistic, but for my data-set that information may be useful. I.e. the intended figure should look like:

[image]
Where the dotted lines (of different colors) represent corresponding plots' 95% or 99.7% confidence interval or (mean +/- (2 or 3)*sigma).

N.B. Unfortunately I can't add the figures here since I don't have enough reputation, will appreciate if someone can upload here from the above links.

Answer (score 2):

Something that would be very simple and easy to do, would be to use the `notch=TRUE` argument in the `boxplot()` function (see [?boxplot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html)).  This isn't quite the same as a 95% confidence interval for the mean, but is instead analogous to a 95% CI for the median (which would address your concern about robustness).  It is explained [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/boxplot.stats.html):

> The notches (if requested) extend to +/-1.58 IQR/sqrt(n). This seems
>   to be based on the same calculations as the formula with 1.57 in
>   Chambers et al. (1983, p. 62), given in McGill et al. (1978, p. 16).
>   They are based on asymptotic normality of the median and roughly equal
>   sample sizes for the two medians being compared, and are said to be
>   rather insensitive to the underlying distributions of the samples. The
>   idea appears to be to give roughly a 95% confidence interval for the
>   difference in two medians.